# how to change minimum Height of a grid in gridbag layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Here i am using `gridbag` layout on a panel to add 5 components arranged in 5 rows, i want them to have different height [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r338v.png) but after doing this

```
public void mainpanel3(){

   pupper.setBackground(Color.yellow);
   ptable.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
   lthird.setOpaque(true);
   lthird.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   tffourth.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
   pfifth.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


   outerp3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
   GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();


   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.5;
   c.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.1;
   c.ipady=5;
   c.gridx=0;
   c.gridy=0;       
   outerp3.add(pupper,c);

   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.4;
   c.ipady=20;
   c.gridx=0;
   c.gridy=1;
   outerp3.add(ptable,c);

   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.1;
   c.ipady=5;
   c.gridx=0;
   c.gridy=2;
   outerp3.add(lthird,c);

   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.1;
   c.ipady=5;
   c.gridx=0;
   c.gridy=3;
   outerp3.add(tffourth,c);

   c.weightx=0.5;
   c.weighty=0.1;
   c.ipady=5;
   c.gridx=0;
   c.gridy=4;
   outerp3.add(pfifth,c);

    }
```

This happens

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQWz.png)

the fifth component(a `panel`) color white do not shows up.

Coding about this panel is done in this method only, let me know if you need any other piece of code.

Comment: The `weighty` values for all components is the same. Change this to something like `0.1`, `0.5`, `0.1`, `0.2` and `0.1` for each component respectively, along with `gridheight` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `weighty` values, though `weightx` will always be `1.0` for each component, since each component differ only in terms of it's `height` but not `width`. Here is a working example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagLayoutExample {

    private GridBagConstraints m_GBC;

    public GridBagLayoutExample () {
        m_GBC = new GridBagConstraints ();
        m_GBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        m_GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    }

    private void displayGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "GridBagLayout Example" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ();
        contentPane.setLayout ( new GridBagLayout () );

        addComponent ( contentPane, getPanel (), 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.1 );
        addComponent ( contentPane, getPanel (), 0, 1, 1, 5, 1.0, 0.5 );
        addComponent ( contentPane, getPanel (), 0, 6, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.1 );
        addComponent ( contentPane, getPanel (), 0, 7, 1, 2, 1.0, 0.2 );
        addComponent ( contentPane, getPanel (), 0, 9, 1, 1, 1.0, 0.1 );

        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private void addComponent ( JComponent contentPane, JComponent component,
                                int x, int y, int gridwidth, int gridheight,
                                double weightx, double weighty ) {
        m_GBC.gridx = x;
        m_GBC.gridy = y;
        m_GBC.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        m_GBC.gridheight = gridheight;
        m_GBC.weightx = weightx;
        m_GBC.weighty = weighty;

        contentPane.add ( component, m_GBC );
    }

    private JPanel getPanel () {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setOpaque ( true );
        Color color = new Color ( ( float ) Math.random (), ( float ) Math.random (),
                                ( float ) Math.random (), ( float ) Math.random () );
        panel.setBackground ( color );

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                new GridBagLayoutExample ().displayGUI ();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater ( runnable );
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: img]